# Dual Pricing for GCP Cloud Functions with Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I created a new GCP Project, and created a hello-world serverless cloud function from GCP Console.

I immediately get a mail that a Firebase project has been created as well, and my Cloud Function has been upgraded to 'Blaze' plan of firebase.

My question is, which pricing model should I refer?

https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing - GCP

OR

https://firebase.google.com/pricing - Firebase

There is a difference in both pricing, where if you see in firebase pricing, 125K invocations/month are free, while in GCP Pricing, 2M invocations/month are free.

I am confused on which pricing is applicable if I simply want to use Cloud Functions, because even if I create a function from GCP Console, firebase console also shows the function in its console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the Firebase pricing page.  The 125K/month refers to the Spark plan in the left most column, all of which is completely free for the month.  If your plan is Blaze, you would use the right most column to assess cost.  That column doesn't show the free allowance, just the actual costs beyond the free limit.  If you hover your mouse over the question mark next to "Cloud Functions" on that row, you will see a description that says the first 2,000,000 invocation are free.  This matches the Cloud pricing.  So I believe they are in sync.

If you have questions about billing, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly rather than Stack Overflow, which is for programming questions.

Comment: Actually at the title 'Blaze Plan', its written that "Free usage from Spark plan included", which led me to assume that there is a difference in free quota, but on hovering to the question mark next to Cloud Functions, I can see that they are indeed in sync! Makes sense now. I actually reached out to Firebase support, but haven't heard back for a while. Anyway, this clarifies it for me.